# Dynamics CRM 2016 onpre - Incoming Email failure issues

Tags: email, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, server-side-sync

Currently using **Server-Side Synchronization** for process email.

Server profile configured with POP3-SMTP profile type.

**for gmail** - 
incoming: **pop.gmail.com** , outgoing: **smtp.gmail.com**
Authenticate for incoming: Credentials Specified by user or queue 
Authenticate for outgoing: Credentials Specified in Email Server Profile
Incoming port: **995; SSL-Enabled; Authenticate protocol-Basic**
Outgoing port: **587; SSL-Enabled; Authenticate protocol-Basic** (test result success)
Outgoing port: **465; SSL-Enabled; Authenticate protocol-Basic** (test result failure)

I had Approved the mailbox with system admin role
Specified Credentials for Email Processing in mailbox (email and password)
incoming email: Server-Side Synchronization or Email Router
outgoing email: Server-Side Synchronization or Email Router

Thats all the setting I had done in my dynamics crm 2016 on-premise. 
the version of my crm is CRM2016 (8.0.0.1088) (DB 8.0.0.1088)

After approved the mailbox and test & enable mailbox. The result only outgoing is success(with port 587) and incoming is failure. My Gmail is able to receive the outgoing email.

The alert message for incoming failure is **An unexpected error occurred while receiving email. Mailbox CRM Admin didn't synchronize. The owner of the associated email server profile gmail server has been notified.**

Does anyone know what I missed to config or any solution can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Some things to verify on GMail side in order for it to play nice with CRM:

- POP has to be enabled
- Allow Less Secure Apps
- Unlock Captcha
- port for pop.gmail.com in CRM mail setup should be 995
- port for smtp.gmail.com in CRM mail setup should be 587 (you already got this right)

Comment: Thx for ur respond...
those setting i alrdy set up
but the incoming email still failure